# How to avoid Persistence of a Factory Girl object

Tags: rspec, persistence, factory-bot

I have several rspec tests that use Factory_girl. It is used on MongoDB with MongoId in a Rails 3 app.

Somewhere along the line, I test against invalid values: expecting validation-errors. After that, anytime I call `Factory(:user)`, it fails, because of validation errors. I would expect an entirely new and clean object, when I call Factory(:user), not a re-used, battered one.

Example code below, illustrates the *user_spec.rb* adding invalid items to "roles". The user model successfully marks the record as *invalid*.

A little further in the specs, a *sidebar_helper_spec.rb* need to instantiate an `@user`, and there it fails, telling me that the invalid  role "foo" is there. But you can clearly see that this role is not present in the *factory.rb*.

Is this expected behaviour? Can I toggle the persistence (or caching?) with a config option?

```
## models/user_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'
describe User do
  describe 'roles' do
    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory.build(:user)
    end
    it 'should require a role' do
      @user.roles = nil
      @user.should_not be_valid
    end
    it 'should allow one role from set of defined roles' do
      #@user.roles is preset in factory with "jobseeker"
      @user.should be_valid
    end
    it 'should reject undefined roles' do
      @user.roles << "foo"
      @user.should_not be_valid
    end
    it 'should allow multiple roles' do
      @user.roles = ["banned", "jobseeker"]
      @user.should be_valid
    end
  end
end

## helpers/sidebar_helper_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'
describe SidebarHelper do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user) #fails with Mongoid::Errors::Validations: Validation failed - Roles foo is an invalid role.
    @profile = Factory.create(:profile)
  end

  # Has many specs, but all Fail on error in the before(:each)
end

## Actual factory.rb

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.password    'mischief managed'
  f.email       'h.potter@gryffindor.hogwards.edu.wiz'
  f.roles       ['jobseeker']
end
Factory.define :employer do |f|
  f.password    'butterscotch'
  f.email       'dumbledore@staff.hogwards.edu.wiz'
  f.roles       ['employer']
end

Factory.define :profile do |f|
  f.available true
  f.sync false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` creates a *new* array `["banned", "jobseeker"]` and sets it to `@user.roles`:

```
# should allow multiple roles
@user.roles = ["banned", "jobseeker"]
```

BUT `<<` *appends* `"foo"` to the already existing array (i.e. modifies the existing array!):

```
# should reject undefined roles
@user.roles << "foo"
```

FactoryGirl is *not* reusing the same user object, but its re-using the same `roles` attribute. Just change the `roles` array to be dynamically created each time in the factory:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  ...
  f.roles       { ['jobseeker'] }
end
Factory.define :employer do |f|
  ...
  f.roles       { ['employer'] }
end
```

Either this, *OR* avoid using `<<` or any method which changes an existing array/variable, and instead use `=` which uses a new object. e.g.

```
# should reject undefined roles
@user.roles = [ "foo" ]
```